# $(a,b) = [a,b]?$ Are these vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I was explaining something to my friend when we ran into this question that I couldn't clearly answer.

Does $(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$?
Are these different notations for a single object sitting in one particular space, or are these distinctive objects in different spaces?

We say that $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, but we also say $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. No big deal...but then do we say $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ also?

I have only learned Cartesian product, $$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$ Is $$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$ another common definition? Are these even distinct or just two ways of naming the set?

Comment: It depends how you define $\mathbb{R}^2$..... trivially.

Comment: I think when specifying a particular matrix shape, it's more correct (and certainly more consistent with the convention for general rectangular matrices) to write $\mathbb R^{2 \times 1}$ for the set of column vectors and $\mathbb R^{1 \times 2}$ for the set of row vectors, and reserve $\mathbb R^{2}$ to refer to ordered pairs $(a,b)$ which are not matrices at all. But that's just my opinion. Certainly there are authors who disagree, so it's best to be flexible and infer the notation from the context.

Comment: One serious unavoidable question: what you mean by "the same thing". Also, what is the *definition* of ${\bf R}^2$?

Comment: I will try to clarify.

Comment: It's a common convention (though certainly not universal) to identify column vectors (in $\mathbb R^{2 \times 1}$) with points (in $\mathbb R^2$), while treating the row vector $[a \; b]$ as a different object obtained by transposing; i.e. $[a\; b] = (a,b)^T.$

Comment: No matter how you look at it, *theses* usually aren't vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. ;-) (That is, there's a typo in the title.)